# Extracting text strings in R

Tags: r, regex

I've a column like this:

```
> PREFI.(S): NETWORK SA|ADV.(A/S):JOHN SMITH SANT'ANNA (30652/RS) AND OTHER(A/S)|RECDO.(A/S): CLAUDIA TRROMMER|ADV.(A/S): LOUISE (52417/RS)

> PREFI.(S): RUTH SEIXAS|ADV.(A/S): LOPES SOUTO (47706/RS)|RECDO.(A/S): MARTINS (64285/RS)
```

I would like to:
1) split values separated by |
2) get only text between ")" or ":" and non-letter characteres/end of the line

Results would be:

```
 NETWORK SA 
 JOHN SMITH
 AND OTHER
 CLAUDIA TRROMMER
 LOUISE RUTH
```

etc

I think I've done the first part sucefully

```
docs <- str_split(processos$partes,"\\|")
```

but I can't figure out the last part - even after some tries with regex lookbehind/ahead

Comment: What do you mean by non-letter? is space not considered as non-letter??

Comment: can you show the regex you have tried so far

Comment: or you can do:`lapply(strsplit(processos$partes, '\\|'),gsub,pattern = '.*:|\\(.*?\\)',replacement = '')`

Comment: Your sample data and expected results (and rules as well) are out of sync. Please update the question with true to life data and exact expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution using **tidyverse** and the **stringr** functions:

```
> library(tidyverse)

> x <- "
+ > PREFI.(S): NETWORK SA|ADV.(A/S):JOHN SMITH SANT'ANNA (30652/RS) AND OTHER(A/S)|RECDO.(A/S): CLAUDIA TRROMMER|ADV.(A/S): LOUISE (52417/RS) ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 

> # split on "|"
> xs <- str_split(x, "\\|")[[1]]

> # extract the data
> str_extract_all(xs, "\\):[ a-zA-Z]*") %>%
+   unlist() %>%
+   sub("^..", "", .)  # get rid of "):"
[1] " NETWORK SA"       "JOHN SMITH SANT"   " CLAUDIA TRROMMER"
[4] " LOUISE "          " RUTH SEIXAS"      " LOPES SOUTO "    
[7] " MARTINS "
```